# Problems with vim, i removed it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim

I'm a new user in linux. The problem is that when i tried to run the VI (or vim) text editor, i realised that it worked really different as i remembered it used to. Example, when i try to put in mode of "insert", in the downside doesn't appear "INSERT", or when i try to delete with the backspace key, it doesn't delete... it moves the cursor back, and does nothing.

So i thought that removing it and re-installing it again would work, and removed it by:

`apt-get --purge remove vim-common`

But now when i try:

`apt-cache search vim`

it throws nothing, and now i don't know how to install it again. Any help? thanks people

Comment: how about `apt-get install vim`?

Comment: t threw 'E: Unable to locate package vim'. Also, when i try 'apt-get update', it updates some things, and others throws "404 not found". Anyway, it doesn't work when i try again with 'sudo apt-get install vim... Thanks!!

Comment: You might need to switch to another software repository. Read more about it here: (I assume you're using Ubuntu. Debian is almost the same) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories?action=show&redirect=AddingRepositoriesHowto

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: mmm the problem is that the contents.. occupy around 2500 characters and it's too long for an answer here... what should i do?

Comment: i put it in another answer, down this message

Comment: well.. i can answer only in 6 hours..

Comment: @Gerardo put in your question (Not another answer)

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt-get install vim` should do it.

Comment: it threw 'E: Unable to locate package vim'. Also, when i try 'apt-get update', it updates some things, and others throws "404 not found". Anyway, it doesn't work when i try again with 'sudo apt-get install vim... Thanks!!